# Создание бесконечно повторяющихся анимаций

Tags: ios, objective-c, анимация

Нужно создать одновременно 20 бесконечно повторяющихся анимаций с разной задержкой. Анимация состоит из перехода `[_imageView setAlpha:0];` в `[_imageView setAlpha:1];` Все работает хорошо. Проблема в том, что девайс сильно и быстро нагревается.

Код для одной анимации

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(148, 0, 17, 18)];
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag.png"];
            [self.view addSubview: _imageView];
            [_star setAlpha:0];
            [_star setAlpha:1];

    } completion:nil];
```

Можно ли снизить нагрузку на девайс?

Comment: может заранее вместо альфы создавать 10 или сколько там получится кадров анимации перехода от одного цвета другой? какой там у вас бэкграунд? можно от альфы избавиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя странное создание и добавление _imageView в блоке анимации. Попробуй вынести создание куда-нибудь на пару уровней выше.
Также сделай через свой таймер, так ты сможешь управлять плавностью (и нагревом соответсвенно).

Если и это не поможет, то сделай программно 10-20-30 картинок-кадров (то что должно быть на экране) и меняй их. Тогда процу не нужно будет постоянно расчитывать прозрачность.

В крайнем случае - OpenGL :)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от самих функций, если они требуют минимально много ресурсов, то девайс и будет греться, их реализация у тебя и так минимально проста, попробуй использовать менее требовательные функции для отрисовки а так, уменьшить нагрев не получится, да и у яблоко-фонов нет хорошего охлаждения и отвода тепла, так что нагрев это обычное дело, ну если он не превышает 70 градусов